# Handlebars renders extra empty objects from json array in Node Express app

Tags: javascript, json, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to take the data from a call to REST API, and render it as a list using Handlebars, which is my view engine in a Node Express App

Here is my route:

```
router.get('api/projects', function(req, res){

    Project.find(function(err, projects){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        console.log(projects);

        res.render('list-view', projects);
    });
});
```

The "projects" JSON array contains different projects with Name and _id keys

Here is my html on list-view.hbs:

```
{{#each .}}

<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="caption">
    <h5> Name: {{name}} </h5>
  </div>
</div>

{{/each}}
```

For some reason, my list-view page will render the projects in a list as planned, but then will always show a few empty projects at the end of the list.  I can't figure out why.  So say I have 8 projects in my projects array...my page will render all 8 correctly, but 11 in total because the last few are empty.  I used console.log(projects) to verify that there were only 8 projects in the array.  Any ideas on why I am getting extra?

Comment: Try printing index of the current array item using {{@index}}

Comment: it indexes out the extra list items as well.  My array has 8 items.  The index goes to 11 (spinal tap!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this.  the projects json Array needed to be passed to handlebars as a single object:

```
router.get('/api/projects', function(req, res){

    Project.find(function(err, projects){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.render('list-view', {projects: projects});
    });
});
```

And then my #each helper looks like this:

```
    {{#each projects}}
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
       <h5> Name: {{name}} </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

Now the list is rendered properly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the accepted answer,

Having

- `res.render('list-view', {projects: projects})` in your JavaScript and
- `{{#each projects}}` in your Handlebars template

is equivalent to having

- `res.render('list-view', projects)` in your JavaScript and
- `{{#each .}}` or `{{#each this}}` in your Handlebars template.

Your problem may be that you are passing in an object from the API which includes all serializable properties.

Try using this instead:

`res.render('list-view', projects.get());`

`.get()` returns only the array that we are concerned with.